# Do we have any kendo treeview kind of control supporting angular2/4

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, controls, treeview

**KendoUI** does not support **treeview** control with **angular2/4** right now so i am searching for any 3rd party treeview control supporting angular4.

Answer (score 0):

Kendo indeed doesn't currently have an Angular2/4 TreeView but they are planning to make it in the future.

In the mean time, I've come across [this TreeView](https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs) which is quite robust with a long list of features, including drag & drop, virtual scrolling, events, templates and more.